# Upgrading Python package in Redhat Software Collections (RHSCL)

Tags: python, pip, rhel, software-collections

I'm using SCL to manage different versions of Python on a machine, but I'm having trouble updating and installing packages at the SCL level.

I am trying to upgrade pip. First I tried

```
scl enable python27 'pip install -U pip'
```

but I do not have permissions to touch the SCL python site-packages.

Then I run

```
sudo scl enable python27 'pip install -U pip'
```

this completes successfully. However, this happens:

```
$ scl enable python27 pip --version
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
      from pip import main 
  ImportError: No module named pip.
```

`$ sudo scl enable python27 pip --version` works, however.

Upon further inspection, it looked like the `site-packages/pip` directory was created with the wrong permissions.

What is the recommended way to manage parts of an SCL install that require root?